# adjusting array output for user timezone

Tags: php, arrays, timezone, timezone-offset, php-carbon

**Important information to know:**

- Database stores user timezone offset as a digit (ex: A user in  EST has a timezone column with value -4"
- Server time is in UTC

I am returning a query with aggregate data grouped by weekday and hour in hopes of displaying it on a heatmap.

So far this is what I have.

```
$timezone = Auth::user()->timezone;

$week_data = DB::select('SELECT COUNT(id) as total, WEEKDAY(created_at) AS week_day ,HOUR(created_at) as hours 
FROM messages
GROUP BY week_day, hours');
```

with some examples: 
[image]

in this example, 'week_day' is a numeric representation of the day of the week (0 = monday, 6 = sunday)
and hours is a numeric representation of the hour of the day (in 24 hour format)

Currently, an object with week_day->2 and hours->23 means Wednesday at 11PM **IN UTC**

After getting the query results, i separate the data using a foreach loop where $new_array is a variable I previously instantiated (not shown)

```
 foreach ($week_data as $data)
    {
        if ($data->week_day == 0)
        {
            $new_array['Monday'][$data->hours] = $data;
        }
        elseif ($data->week_day == 1)
        {
            $new_array['Tuesday'][$data->hours] = $data;
        }elseif ($data->week_day == 2)
        {
            $new_array['Wednesday'][$data->hours] = $data;
        } elseif ($data->week_day == 3)
        {
            $new_array['Thursday'][$data->hours] = $data;
        }
        elseif ($data->week_day == 4)
        {
            $new_array['Friday'][$data->hours] = $data;
        }
        elseif ($data->week_day == 5)
        {
            $new_array['Saturday'][$data->hours] = $data;
        }
        elseif ($data->week_day == 6)
        {
            $new_array['Sunday'][$data->hours] = $data;
        }
    }
```

Now, I am trying to find a way where I can adjust the array data to reflect the offset of the user's timezone. Therefore, the information should somehow be processed before it reaches the foreach loop with the switch case. Has anyone ever dealt with this issue before? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this example I will use these variables:

```
$week_day = 1;
$hours    = 23;
$TimeZone = -4;
```

Fill an array with days of week names coherent with your week system (this example has 0=Monday, 6=Sunday ):

```
$weekdays = [ 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday' ];
```

Create new UTC DateTime object:

```
$date = new Datetime( "{$weekdays[$week_day]}, {$hours}:00 UTC" );
```

Change TimeZone:

```
$date->setTimezone( new DateTimeZone($TimeZone) );
```

and you have the date in desired TimeZone.

To use the week day name:

```
$weekday_name = $date->format( 'l' );
```

To use the 0-24 hour (w/out leading zero):

```
$hour = $date->format( 'G' );
```

You can find complete available output format ad [`date()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) section of php manual.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's `CONVERT_TZ` function converts `DATETIME` values from one timezone to another. If you use this function when selecting out the data you won't need to change the PHP code at all.

If `$timezone` is entered by the user, you'll need to edit this code to prevent SQL injection. I'm not au fait with your database abstraction library otherwise I'd have done it for you.

```
$timezone = Auth::user()->timezone;

$week_data = DB::select("
    SELECT COUNT(id) as total,
           WEEKDAY(CONVERT_TZ(created_at, '+0:00', '$timezone:00')) AS week_day,
           HOUR(CONVERT_TZ(created_at, '+0:00', '$timezone:00')) AS hours 
    FROM messages
    GROUP BY week_day, hours");
```

Storing the user's timezone as a number of hours from UTC is a bad idea, however. You won't be able to account correctly for Daylight Savings Time. Better to use a named timezone or location.